# Safety differences between full wallet encryption and only encrypting the private keys?

Tags: electrum, encryption, wallet-security

I'm a newcomer in the Bitcoin world and I wanted to ask the following questions regarding wallet security: What are the safety differences between fully encrypting the wallet.dat file and only encrypting the wallet's private keys, like the Electrum wallet does? Does the latter option imply any additional security concerns compared to full encryption? In what cases should someone choose either option?

Thank you very much.